# SwiftUI - How to make UIViewControllerRepresentable transparent?

Tags: swiftui

I have a `UIViewControllerRepresentable` which I'm presenting like this:

```
.fullScreenCover(item: $userToPresent) { user in
    ProfileCardViewRepresentable(user: user)
        .ignoresSafeArea()
}
```

The thing is, I want to have transparency on its background so that the view behind it is visible. If I present the ViewController from another ViewController and set the `modalPresentationStyle` to `.overFullScreen`, it works! But when I try to present it from a `SwiftUI` view, it just shows a grey background.

Here's my Representable:

```
struct ProfileCardViewRepresentable: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    let user: NPUserDataModel

    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> ProfileCardViewController {
        let vc = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ProfileCardViewController") as! ProfileCardViewController

        vc.user = user
        vc.modalPresentationStyle = .overFullScreen

        return vc
    }

    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: ProfileCardViewController, context: Context) {}
}
```

Any idea what is wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/65295500/12299030?

Comment: Yep it did!! 