# How to make the background of a fullscreencover transparent?

Tags: swift, swiftui

This is what I want to achieve: [image]

This is what I got: [image]

I tried embeding the `VStack` in another `VStack` with a `.background(.gray.opacity(90))` but it didn't do anything. I am using a `fullScreenCover`:

```
let width = UIScreen.main.bounds.width
.fullScreenCover(isPresented: $showCover) {
BuyWithPointsView(type: type).frame(width: (width * (91.733 / 100)), height: (width * (66.667 / 100)))
}
```

**EDIT**:
I tried implementing this answer: [SwiftUI: Translucent background for fullScreenCover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64301041/swiftui-translucent-background-for-fullscreencover)

```
.fullScreenCover(isPresented: $showCover) {
                    ZStack {
                        ZStack {
                            Color.gray.opacity(0.1).edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                        }.background(BackgroundBlurView())
                        BuyWithPointsView(type: type).frame(width: (width * (91.733 / 100)), height: (width * (66.667 / 100)))
                    }
                }
struct BackgroundBlurView: UIViewRepresentable {
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIView {
        let view = UIVisualEffectView(effect: UIBlurEffect(style: .light))
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            view.superview?.superview?.backgroundColor = .clear
        }
        return view
    }
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIView, context: Context) {}
}
```

This lead to this result: [image] However this result does not really make the background see through like I want it to be. Changing the opacity and color didn't do much.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to set a fullScreenCover background opacity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65295388/is-there-a-way-to-set-a-fullscreencover-background-opacity)

Answer (score 1):

I found this cleaner solution for the transparent background without any flicker issues.

```swift
struct ClearBackgroundView: UIViewRepresentable {
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIView {
        return InnerView()
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIView, context: Context) {
    }
    
    private class InnerView: UIView {
        override func didMoveToWindow() {
            super.didMoveToWindow()
            
            superview?.superview?.backgroundColor = .clear
        }
        
    }
}
```

Usage

```swift
PresenterView()
    .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $isPresented) {
        PresentedView()
            .background(ClearBackgroundView())
    }
```

Comment: I had been searching for the fix to the flickering issue, which caused other exceptions downstream and found this by chance. Thanks @ahmed

Answer (score 1):

iOS 16.4 provides [.presentationBackground](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/presentationbackground(_:)?changes=_8) to modify your modal backgrounds. Yay to yoinking `UIViewRepresentable` workarounds :)

Usage

```
.fullScreenCover(isPresented: $isPresented) {
    YourView()
        .presentationBackground(.clear)
}
```